# Created LDAP User - not found in terminal

Tags: ldap, openldap

I created my LDAP user in phpldapadmin, and when searching for this user with ldapsearch -x i found the user in my terminal.

But when trying to log in to my user, I get an error saying your user does not exist:

```
su test
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's saying: "No passwd entry for user 'test'", then you might have to follow the steps in: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html, under "LDAP Authentication". This is what helped me. You also need to edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to include the following:

```
[Seat:*]
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

This should allow part of the option to log in via the Ubuntu login screen.

I'm currently trying to figure out the rest of the process for authenticating through that Ubuntu/LightDM login screen. There's a guide at: https://www.danbishop.org/2015/01/30/ubuntu-14-04-ultimate-server-guide/ That I am trying to follow. But, this is for 14.04, so there may be some changes between that and 16.04.